# Prove that stabilizer subgroups of G are conjugate to each other

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Suppose that a group $G$ acts on a set $X$. Show that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ in X are in
>   the same $G$-orbit, then their stabilizer subgroups of $G$ are conjugate
>   to each other.

My proof:

Assume $x_1 = g_1x$ and $x_2 = g_2 x$ for some $g_1, g_2 \in G$. Let $h \in G_{x_1}$. We claim that $g_2g_1^{-1}hg_1g_2^{-1}$ is in $G_{x_2}$, thus proving that the two stabilizer subgroups are conjugate to each other.

Indeed, 
$$\begin{align}
x_1&=g_1x\\
g_2g_1^{-1}x_1&=g_2x\\
g_2g_1^{-1}hx_1&=g_2x\\
g_2g_1^{-1}hg_1x&=g_2x\\
(g_2g_1^{-1}hg_1g_2^{-1})x_2&=x_2\\
\end{align}$$ as desired.

I think it is a bit messy. Can you please comment on my proof and leave your own proof so that I can learn in a better way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof is fine, but you might start with $x_2=gx_1$ instead of introducing $x$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are in the same orbit, so $x=gy$ for some $g$. If $h$ stabilizes $y$, then $ghg^{-1}x=ghy=gy=x$. This gives an injective homomorphism from $Stab(y)$ to $Stab(x)$. You can verify that $h\mapsto g^{-1}hg$ is its inverse, so the two groups are conjugate.

Comment: That's clear! Thanks!